# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Тут такое дело, начинаю программировать на php и решил начать с формы авторизации и регистрации, взял на одном сайте и так получилось что написано было на старых командах MySQL, решил переписать сразу на MySQLi, и вот сейчас сижу и перепробовал десятки способов исправить ошибку, но получается всё также. Можете помочь?

Вот отрезок кода:

```html
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'Admin';
$db_password = 'vfOm1DtG304nmyu4';
$database = 'site';
// Подключаемся к БД mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password);
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $database);

if($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: ". $conn->connect_error);
}

 $sql = ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS registr_users (`id` INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, `date_created` DATETIME NOT NULL, `login` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL, `password` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL, `email` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY  (`id`), UNIQUE (`login`) ) 
    ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6849") or die();
$result = mysqli_query($database, $query) or die();

//Записываем в БД данные форм
$query="INSERT INTO `registr_users` (`id`, `date_created`, `login`, `password`, `email`)
                  VALUES ('', NOW(), '$login', '$password', '$email')"; 
        $result = $query;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы передали `$database = 'site'`, а метод `mysqli_query()` принимает два параметра: `mysqli $link` - ваш коннект к базе `$conn` и второй `string $query`, сделайте так:

```php
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die();
```

Подробнее в [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)