# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in D:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\proverki.php on line 120 Connection error1

Tags: php

Не понимаю, что ему не нравится?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
 * A Design by GraphBerry
 * Author: GraphBerry
 * Author URL: http://graphberry.com
 * License: http://graphberry.com/pages/license
-->
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset=UTF-8>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Библиотека WGNF</title>
    <!-- Load Roboto font -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- Load css styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pluton.css" />
    <!--[if IE 7]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pluton-ie7.css" />
        <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.cslider.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.bxslider.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css" />
    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-touch-icon-72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-57.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/ico/favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="brand">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" width="120" height="40" alt="Logo" />
                    <!-- This is website logo -->
                </a>
                <!-- Navigation button, visible on small resolution -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <i class="icon-menu"></i>
                </button>
                <!-- Main navigation -->
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse pull-right">
                    <ul class="nav" id="top-navigation">

                </div>
                <!-- End main navigation -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    </header>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #FFD700
        }

        TABLE {
            border: 4px solid #000;
            color: black;
        }

        a {
            color: #008000;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a:visited {
            color: #000;
        }

        a:hover {
            color: #000;
        }
    </style>
    <section class="box-with-image-right section-top-space">

        <div class="center">

            <div class="green-line"></div>

            <a href="admin.php" type="button"><-----Вернуться назад </a>

            <form id="checking-form" action="#" method="post"></form>
            <table border=1>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="checking" form="checking-form">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button form="checking-form" type="submit">Введите дату</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <td>День сдачи</td>
                    <td>Читатель</td>
                    <td>Книга</td>
                <?

                        include("dbinsert.php");
                        $checking = $_POST["checking"];


                        $result = null;

                        if ($checking) {
                            $query = "SELECT `Date_vozvrata`,`ID_Zakazchika`,`Name_Book` from `zakaz` WHERE (Date_vozvrata <= '$checking')";
                            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Connection error1");  
                        }

                        if ($result) {
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                            {
                                ?>


                <tr>



                                    <td><? print $row['Date_vozvrata']?></td>
                                    <td><? print $row['ID_Zakazchika']?></td>
                                    <td><? print $row['Name_Book']?></td> 
                                <?
                            }
                        }


                        mysqli_close($link);

                    ?>
                </tr>


        </div>

    </section>



    <footer>



        <nav>

            <ul class="left">





            </ul>

        </nav>

        <div class="clear">
        </div>

        </div>

    </footer>

    <!--
    facebook SDK
    -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

    <script src="_assets/_libs/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="_assets/_libs/no-ui-slider/jquery.nouislider.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="_assets/_libs/smoothscroll.js"></script>
    <script src="_assets/_libs/parallax.js"></script>
    <script src="_assets/_js/functions.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: у вас в `mysqli_query($link, $query)` переменная `$link` равна `null`

Comment: @ArchDemon то есть просто задать ей какое-либо значение?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Warning: mysqli\_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1019701/warning-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli)